# How to run Main.py automatically in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I prefer using a Java-like organization with my projects. For instance, each class has a different `.py` file as well as class `Main`, which only contains main function.

Each time I make a change in one of my classes, I need to click on Main and run the code `(Ctrl+Shift+F10)` from there.

How can I define my `Main` class as my `main()` function just as in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create "run configurations" like in Eclipse.

The name of the thing in the dropdown is the run that you want and should not change between changing files.  Clicking the triangle (or using alt-shift-X under the eclipse keymap) should run that configuration.  In the dropdown you have the option of selecting whatever file you want to run.

[image: run area]